# How add association between account model and transaction model in bank account application in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I am newbie in rails and I am building a bank account application in rails. The user and account data is already available in seeds. User has only one account so the association here is of one-to-one. However one account can have multiple transactions. So the association is of one-to-many. So when user clicks on 'transact' option for his account,he is directed to transaction page for debit/credit transaction. But once the transaction is performed, the details of transaction along with account_id should be stored in a transaction table.

My code for accounts and transactions is as follows:
Model Account:

```
class Account < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :transaction
end
```

Account Controller:

```
class AccountsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @accounts = Account.all
  end
end
```

Transaction Model:

```
class Transaction < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :account
end
```

Transaction Controller:

```
class TransactionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @transaction = Transaction.new
  end

 def create
   @transaction = Transaction.new(transaction_params)
 end

 private

 def transaction_params
   params.require(:transaction).permit(:amount, :commit)
 end
 end
```

I have added account_id column in transaction table. Can anybody please help to setup the association??
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have transactions and for particular account, and you are proceeding transaction through account.

**Scenario-1** :

1. Checked in particular account & proceed transaction. (create view)
2. Nested routes for transaction is created, ex. for new action, `/accounts/:account_id/transactions/new`
3. create filter, `before_filter :find_account` for

   ```
   @account = Account.find(params[:account_id]) if params[:account_id]
   ```
4. In new action of TransactionsController,

   ```
   @transaction = @account.transactions.new
   ```

   You need to update transaction_params in case of changes

**Scenorio-2** :

If you are not creating nested routing, simply provide @account_list_hash where you will select account_id by using select_list in view. And new action will be

```
    # code to pass array for account_id select_list by method account_list_hash
    @transaction = @Transaction.new
```

I will update in case of further clarification.

Answer (score 0):

In Account model change this:

```
has_many: transaction to has_many: transactions
```

Please follow the naming conventions.

And in TransactionsController create a **before_action** like below.

```
before_action :set_account_id

def set_account_id
 @account = Account.find_by(id: params[:account_id]
end
```

While creating a transaction create using the Account details returned by **set_account_id** method.

```
 class TransactionsController < ApplicationController
   def create
    @transaction = @account.transactions.new(transaction_params)
    @transaction.save!
   end
 end
```

Comment: It is throwing error as : `undefined method `create' for nil:NilClass` in create action

Comment: did you set the before action? and where did you placed the Transact button?

Comment: you don't have an account for which you want to create transaction. Either your account do not exist or your `account_id` is not valid / not coming in params

Comment: The transact now button is in accounts_views/index page, which redirects to transactions/new page

Comment: Place `binding.pry` in transactions new action and check if you're getting account_id in params.

Comment: Ok i'll try this

Comment: hey @Neha did you nested routes? like nesting transaction model inside Article in `routes.rb`. If not, you cannot get the account id inside the new or create block.

Comment: @UdAY Your are wrong, how can you call create on ActiveRecord::CollectionProxy